# Strange behavior with bootstrap taginput and typeahead - selection shadow?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tags, bootstrap-typeahead

I want to implement a tag input on my form and have the available tags auto-suggested; so these are the libraries I am using:

- http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/
- https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

This is how I initialize the two libs together:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#tags').tagsinput({
        typeahead: {
            source: ["mysql-server", "apache", "php", "nginx", "phpmyadmin"]
        }
    });
});
```

When I begin typing `ph` it starts suggesting two available tags like this:

[image]

When I make a selection, e.g. `php` - this what happens:

[image]

This happens with all tags, it does the tag and then there's a shadow version of the selected tag from the suggestion.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you prepare a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Having same issue any help or update on above question?

Comment: i reproduced it at jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sairfan1/po4jpehb/3/)